# Role hierachy in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, roles, wso2-identity-server

I consume the wso2 is administration web service to obtain user information. Using this service I can get all the roles the user is member of, but the roles the user is member of by inheritance.

For example, There are role1 and role2. Role2 is member of Role1 in active directory and when I obtain the user information, I just get that user is member of role2. I need to get the role1 as well since role2 is a child of role1.

How could this be archieved?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to disappoint you, but I believe it won't work with the default userstore manager. It seems for the group search only a singe LDAP query is executed, so direct group membership is returned (no groups in the groups).

Comment: Yes this is not support OOB.

Comment: not :( but the requested functionality is not to be achieved by built-in tools. Indeed - there may be a way to get a flat list of the groups/role writing a custom userstore manager querying AD recursively  for groups if found.

Comment: we are trying to set nested groups in a claim. To archieve that, we create a custom claim handler and retrieve the nested groups in Java. We also tried to set a custom claim using a extensible match rule (http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+User+Related+Searches-AllGroupsAUserIsAMemberOfIncludingNestedGroups) with no success

Comment: we're doing something similar - extending the userstore manager, overwriting the doGetExternalRoleListOfUser (the roles are read from another source). The problem is that you will have to recursively follow the inner group references up to some level..

Comment: good point Gabriel, we'll give it a try too. I do not know if you use active directory, but there is a rule to retrieve neste roles. Unfortunatelly we failed to make it work (http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941)

Comment: we finally override the method doGetExternalRoleListOfUser  but getting security error. Have you faced that kind of errors? I have posted another question for this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38116572/java-security-error-when-overriding-dogetexternalrolelistofuser-in-wso2-is)